# LINQ query, group by and multiple sums

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following table:

```
|   PersonId   |   Year   |   Month   |   Amount   |
----------------------------------------------------
|   123        |   2017   |   3       |   5.5      |
----------------------------------------------------
|   312        |   2017   |   3       |   6        |
----------------------------------------------------
|   888        |   2018   |   3       |   5.5      |
----------------------------------------------------
|   123        |   2018   |   3       |   5.5      |
----------------------------------------------------
```

What I am hoping to get, is an object with the month number, and 2 sums; Sum of amount/month this year and same sum, but last year.
For example: month:3, sumCurrent:11, sumLast: 11.5.

My following code gets the sumCurrent, but I don't know how to change it to get what I need.

```
var ListOfMonths = MyCollection
                .Where(x => x.Year == Datetime.Now.Year)
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.Month})
                .Select(c => new
                {
                    motnh = c.Key.Month,
                    mysum = Math.Round(((c.Sum(x => x.Amount) / 365) * (decimal)0.99), 0)
                });
```

Comment: Do the group by year and month and then select it should give you the required result

Comment: Could you please explain in detail:- `What I am hoping to get, is an object with the month number, and 2 sums; Sum of amount/month this year and same sum, but last year. For example: month:3, sumCurrent:11, sumLast: 11.5.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to grouping by year after month then you have to do it in the same sequence like below,

```
var listOfMonths = MyCollection.GroupBy(obj => obj.Month).Select(groupingObj => new
            {
                month = groupingObj.Key,
                yearSum = groupingObj.GroupBy(x => x.Year).Select(newGroup => newGroup.Sum(s => s.Amount))
            });
```

If you want the year as well to denote which sum belongs to which year you have to include it in select like,

```
yearSum = groupingObj.GroupBy(x => x.Year).Select(newGroup => new { year = newGroup.Key, Total = newGroup.Sum(s => s.Amount) })
```

Hopefully, this answers your question.

Comment: Typo: `groupingObj.Key.Month` is  `groupingObj.Key`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't group by Month, but by the combination of [Year, Month].

To improve efficiency do this only for the years you want to investigate.

```
int thisYear = DateTime.UtcNow.Year;
int lastYear = thisYear - 1;

var query = MyCollection
    .Where(item => item.Year >= lastYear)
    .GroupBy(item => new {Year = item.Year, Month = item.Month), // Key
        item => item.Amount)                                     // Values

    // only if you want some ordering:
    .OrderBy(group => group.Key.Year)
    .ThenBy(group => group.Key.Month)

    // calculate the sum of all items in the group. Remember the year and the month
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Year = group.Key.Year,           // omit if you won't use this
        Month = group.Key.Month,
        Sum = group.Sum(),
     });

var thisYearsResult = query.Where(fetchedItem => fetchedItems.Year == thisYear)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Years and months might be missing, hence you can't say that lastYear will be in [0] and this year in [1]. That is the main reason that I decided to keep properties year and month

If you want a sequence of years, where every item is a sequence of months with summed values, do a GroupBy Year before a GroupBy month

```
var query = MyCollection
    .Where(item => item.Year >= lastYear)
    .GroupBy(item => item.Year)
    // every group  has Year as key, and all items of that year as elements

    .Select(group => new
    {
         Year = group.Key,
         AmountsPerMonth = group.GroupBy(groupItem => groupItem.Month)
             // every subGroup has the same Year and Month
             .Select(subGroup => new
             {
                 Month = subGroup.Key,
                 Sum = subGroup.Select(subGroupItem => subGroupItem.Amount).Sum(),
             }),
    });
```

Again you might have the problem of missing years and months.

Answer (score 0):

This way you will have access to the Sum of current and last year.

```
var input = new List<dataSo> {
    new dataSo(123, 2016, 3, 5.5m ),
    new dataSo(312, 2016, 3, 6m ),
    new dataSo(123, 2017, 3, 5.5m ),
    new dataSo(312, 2017, 3, 6m ),
    new dataSo(888, 2018, 3, 5.5m ),
    new dataSo(123, 2018, 3, 5.5m )
};


var math = input
            // only the last 2 year
            .Where(x => x.Year >= DateTime.Now.Year-1)
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Month })
            .Select(c => new
            {
                Year = c.Key.Year,
                Month = c.Key.Month,
                Sum = c.Sum(x => x.Amount)
            });
```

Comment: It will actually create two objects for each year. I think he wants one object for each month with years sum listed under them.

Comment: @CoderofCode, sorry  miss read your comment. What 2 object ? One per Year, per Month. Like `{
 Year: 2017,
 Month: 3,
 Sum: 11.5
},
{
 Year: 2017,
 Month: 4,
 Sum: 11.5
},
{
 Year: 2018,
 Month: 3,
 Sum: 11.0
}`